# Cascading Comboboxes in Access Form Not Showing all available options after selections have been made

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was not entirely sure how to search for this question via Google or this site so let me apologize in advance if this a repeat question.

I have an unbound Access Form with 4 cascading comboboxes that are criteria for a query which in turn will create a form and so on so forth. The cascading works beautifully like I would expect and the form generates like it is supposed on a button click. However, I have an issue where I make a selection in one combobox and then make a change in separate combobox, the full list of values no longer shows in the first combobox. Same thing occurs if I click in the combobox and backspace the text that is there.
*Edit*
If I make a selection in Combobox1 and then reclick into Combobox1 only the selection I made is shown instead of the whole list. It appears I did something wrong with making the comboboxes but not sure what property controls that.

I am using a AfterUpdate event to requery the boxes to make them cascading. So it looks like

```
Private Sub Combobox1 AfterUpdate()
Me.Combobox2.Requery
Me.Combobox3.Requery
Me.Combobox4.Requery
```

And the code is repeated in the other boxes that will change as well. I want it so if the user changes their mind or mis-clicks then they would have the option to go back and fix it.

**Edit**

One solution I have tried is to set values to Null in the AfterUpdate event as well. However I realized if I needed to change just one selection I would not want the rest of my values to disappear and reselect them.

I have also tried creating a Union query based on individual queries for the combobox to filter, Combobox1 is used in criteria for Query1 etc. I got it created but the union query still returns all results.

**Edit2**

```
SELECT tblRawData.[Body No], tblRawData.Supplier, tblRawData.[Part Content], tblRawData.[Defect Desc], tblRawData.DateAdded, Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2) AS ModelCode, tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus, tblRawData.Location, tblRawData.Main, tblRawData.Responsibility2, tblRawData.Responsibility1, tblRawData.[Repair Job1], tblRawData.[Repair Job2], tblRawData.[Trim In Time], tblRawData.[S/OFF Date], tblRawData.[Repair Memo], tblRawData.Responsible, tblRawData.Note
FROM tblRawData
WHERE (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND ((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND ((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND ((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus])) OR (((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND ((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND ((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND ((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND ((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null)) OR (((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND ((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND ((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND ((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND ((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND ((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.ThreePanelStatus)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND ((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND ((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND ((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND ((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null)) OR (((Left([tblRawData].[Body No],2))=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND ((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null)) OR (((tblRawData.[Body No])=[Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null)) OR ((([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseBodyNo]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboChooseModelCode]) Is Null) AND (([Forms]![frmTest]![cboSelectThreePanelStatus]) Is Null));
```

Not sure how to get that to show a little cleaner but there is the SQL that is currently being used.

Comment: What SQL are you using to populate the combo boxes? Since they're all linked it's likely that this is where the issue may be.

Comment: agree with jhTuppeny, problem sound like it could be in your source queies for the comboboxes. Are you using 4 individual recordsources? or one for all 4?  Can you show the queries?

Comment: I know it may not be the most efficient (or correct) way but everything is based on one query. Query is based on one table using 4 of the table fields for the criteria. The SQL I believe shows all possible combinations the 4 comboboxes could have. This is not verified since I did not type SQL myself. I have no idea on how to use SQL either which might be part of the issue as well

Comment: If it tells you anything, the WHERE portion of the SQL code is 23 lines long to accomodate

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it looks like it's in the SQL. Posting that is the first stage to a fix.

Comment: @BenMcIntyre SQL has been added to main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to having the AfterUpdate event for the comboboxes, I added a LostFocus event that will requery. Now when the user goes back into a combobox that already has a value and deletes it then clicks somewhere else all the wanted values are shown. It may not be full-proof but it works for now. Code is below.

*Note: cboChooseBodyNo does not have an AfterUpdate event since it is intended to be the last selection made before displaying the results in another form. Does not need to influence what is happening in the other comboboxes.*

```
Private Sub cboChooseModelCode_AfterUpdate()
Me.cboChooseBodyNo.Requery
Me.cboSelectThreePanelStatus.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cboChooseModelCode_LostFocus()
Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cboChooseSupplier_AfterUpdate()
Me.cboChooseBodyNo.Requery
Me.cboSelectThreePanelStatus.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cboChooseSupplier_LostFocus()
Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cboSelectThreePanelStatus_AfterUpdate()
Me.cboChooseBodyNo.Requery
Me.cboChooseSupplier.Requery
Me.cboChooseModelCode.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub cboSelectThreePanelStatus_LostFocus()
Me.Requery
End Sub
```